# Add android studio project to github?

Tags: git, github, android-studio

I have been trying to add my android studio project to github for a while now and keep getting this error:  Can't add remote
            fatal: remote origin already exists.
            during executing git remote add origin

why am I getting this? does anybody have any advice as to how to add android studio projects to github?

Answer (score 1):

Adding your Android Studio project on Github is really simple with the latest versions of Android Studio. Just go to VCS > Import into Version Control > Share project on Github. Add your username and password. And you're done. Once that is done, go to VCS > Git and you'll get all the Git options(adding, committing, pushing etc).

Comment: Remove your project from Github and start again. Let Android Studio do all the work for you.

Comment: I removed all of my repositories from github and still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you have already set a remote destination. So you have to remove the current remote. The best possible solution is using command line, navigate to projects root directory.

```
git remote rm origin
```

This removes the current remote. Then you can add new remote.

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git
```